# Change the file icon of specified file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm having Lots of .pdf files in a specified folder (let it be `E:\Sujith\Files\` and the files are named as `pdfFile_01.pdf`, `pdfFile_02.pdf`, `pdfFile_03.pdf` etc). Now i wanted to change the icon of specified file( `pdfFile_01.pdf`) from it default icon to specified icon( let it be `E:\Sujith\Icons\pdf_new.Ico`). How can i do this from command line or batch file

Answer (score 1):

File type icons are applied per-filetype (not per-file). Only way you can set a different icon for a specific file is by writing an [icon handler shell extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or by using a program that uses one.

Comment: But that are all points to `C++`. I'm using `C#`. Is there any possibility from the command line or using c# libraries?

Comment: If you're going to code yourself, then posting it in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022831/creating-shell-extension-handlers-for-icon-handler-with-c-sharp) is a good idea.

Comment: @un-lucky You can create a shortcut to that PDF file and change it all day long but good luck otherwise~ +1 +1 +1 ... o{\\\\\\\\]::;;::;;::;;::;;::>

Comment: I followed [this Link](http://www.mombu.com/programming/c/t-c-shell-extension-handler-icon-overlay-handler-1568092.html) It don't do anything,